# why GUID uniqueidentifier show value slightly different

Tags: c#, database, sybase

We have an user table which the userId is an uniqueidentifier type in Sybase database. The value we put in is a GUID value from our C# application. When we look at the table via Sybase tool, the value shows as `3835FD60-ACDE-4345-99AB-54263E9A07AE`. When we copy/paste that field to a text file, it shows as `0x3835fd60acde434599ab54263e9a07ae`. When we access that field using  odbc (in python) generates the (Hex) string as 
`3835FD60ACDE434599AB54263E9A07AE`.

Why it shows differently?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Guid is just a set of bytes; it isn't a string. The same as an integer 123 isn't the string "123". There are various ways of displaying it as a human readable string. You can use the format specifier with `Guid.ToString(string)` to choose a format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx

Simply: they chose to use different formats. The Guid is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, UUID/GUID values are stored as a 128 bit integer, so any of the display formats are valid.  The formatted display that we are used to when we are referring to a UUID or GUID is just a transformation of that 128-bit integer into a convenient string format.

In Python, you should be able to pass the value to the `uuid.UUID` class in order to get a UUID object that you can then format in the customary way.